# Making the android app crash

Tags: android, security, nullpointerexception, crash

I am working on a security feature in my android app and want app to crash if a particular condition is met like detection of rooted device, temper detection etc. I am explicitly throwing NullPointerException to crash the app if the security of my app is compromised in above mentioned situations. Is it the correct approach ? Can a hacker somehow catch the exception to still make the program running ?

Answer (score 0):

In a typical environment, your app should stop working and exit. If someone wanted to, they could probably stop the crash with other frameworks like xposed. Rather than throwing an exception, why not just stop your app and exit?

You may try to `finish()` an activity, and/or exit your application with `System.exit(0)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is good suggestion. I want to completely stop my app. Will System.exit(0) work in this case if I have multiple activities ? I was reading some posts saying that it closes the current activity and restarts the app from previous activity.

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper that may depend on your implementation. My only usecase was an activity telling the previous (main) activity to restart. But if you're only checking once you're in say the 2nd layer of activities, doesn't that mean that users who fail the test can still access the 1st? If security is very important, you'll likely need to add many checks at important points in your app.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Allan W's answer above, note that detecting rooted devices, tamper detection etc. is a game of cat and mouse.

It is fairly common in devices using Xposed to hide xposed and root using the fact that you have Xposed. SuHide similarly uses root to hide root. Similar work-arounds exists for Google's device compatibility check.

In my opinion it is unlikely you can make any local information Completely hack-proof - your best option is to keep security critical data on servers you control.